# Building nested menus with one mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Would be possible to build a nested menu with one mysql table? I have been making a table having the following structure but I'm having problem to build up the query

```
ID | Menu  | parent | position | active

 1   test      0         1         1

 2   test2     1         2         1
```

....

Comment: what do you want the query to return?

Comment: I would like to have an array "ParentMenu"=> array('child_1', 'child_2')

Comment: What? What do you call a nested menu given this info, and what is PArentmenu, what is child_1 ?

Comment: I found this post interesting http://wizardinternetsolutions.com/web-database-design/dynamic-multilevel-css-menu-php-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is not the best DB when it comes to storing hierarchical data. It doesn't really have native support for it. So you can either write a recursive function in php that pulls each nested menu out on demand (okay if there are only a few, else the constant round trips to the db really kill app performance) or you can do something like this:

http://explainextended.com/2009/03/17/hierarchical-queries-in-mysql/